# pandas combine multiple dataframes or use as updates

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to concat, join or merge dataframes based on *both* the index and columns? For example, suppose I have a list of dataframes and I want something like

```
df = pandas.fullConcat(dfList)
```

where `df.index` should be the union of the indices in `dfList` `('outer' join)` and `df.columns` should also be the union of the columns in `dfList`. I think all of the concat, join and merge methods just do a join on either the index or the column. I suppose a workaround is stack/unstack or reset_index? Do i miss something ?

Comment: Maybe it makes sense that the joins can only occur on one multi-index at a time. When you have both MultiIndexes and multi-dimensional indexed arrays, the options are many. As a 'work flow' t seems that working with a single MultiIndex during aggregation of data makes the most sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're going to have to reset the index:

```
df = df1.reset_index().merge(df2.reset_index(), on=['index','cols']).set_index('index')
```